# React-Native async function unexpected identifier _this2

Tags: react-native, async-await, remote-debugging

I have this function that I want to wait of the result of and then use it:

```
getUserId = () => {
    fetch("https://www.dummysite.com/mobile/person-id", {
      credentials: "include",
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        Cookie: this.state.auth_token_res
      }
    }).then(res => {
      let id_obj = JSON.parse(res._bodyText);
      console.log("parsed json", id_obj);
      return id_obj.data;
    });
  };
```

I want to use it in this function:

```
async sendID() {
        let user_id = await this.getUserId();
        console.log(user_id);
        OneSignal.sendTags({
          user_id: user_id
        })
          .then(function(tagsSent) {
            // Callback called when tags have finished sending
            console.log("tag is set: ", tagsSent);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("error", err);
          });
  }
```

I don't see any syntax problems, and the app compiles, but when it starts it just hows this error:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHEIs.png)

the other weird this is if i turn on remote debugging on this screen I get a different error:
[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0Wye.png)

here is says that await is not in an async function but it is, and I am not getting syntax error in my editor or in the metro bundler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few things you might have missed. Consider these changes. Although I didn't get a chance to test it, I am confident it will work or at least put you on a right track.

```js
getUserId = () => {
  // return fetch in order to await
  return fetch("https://www.dummysite.com/mobile/person-id", {
    credentials: "include",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Cookie: this.state.auth_token_res
    }
  }).then(res => res.json());
};

// make this an arrow function
sendID = async () => {
  try {
    let user_id = await this.getUserId();
    // after printing then decide what to do here;
    console.log(user_id);

    const tagsSent = await OneSignal.sendTags({
      user_id: user_id
    });
    console.log(tagsSent);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

}
```

Comment: hey i did this but I am getting the same result

Comment: ok getting logs but they are undefined, I do not think that it waits for the results

Comment: I literally just checked this code with different API. It works. Since you don't provide a lot of context here, I am not sure what's going on with your code.

Comment: hm so maybe I am missing something like some babel preset or plugin for async? I am using the default scaffolded project one

Comment: as long as you are on the latest react native version, you should be fine

Comment: Could you check your .babelrc file?

Comment: I am on react-native": "0.57.4"

Comment: I ran this code with React on the browser in codesandbox.io. I didn't set up react native app

Comment: could you send the link to the sandbox?

Comment: ok so it seems good the id part, but the onesignal part returns undefined always, why is that?

Comment: I wish I knew what OneSignal does.

Comment: it is a service for notifications, and it creates a user, and you can set tags on those users, to id them from your side

Comment: What does it suppose to return?